# how to add supremums

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, supremum-and-infimum

I need to prove that $$\sup(S)+\sup(T)=\sup(S+T)$$ I don't understand what $\sup(S+T)$ means, can you show me examples for sets $S$ and $T$ for which this equation holds?

Comment: First off, be careful with the word "group". It has a specific meaning in mathematics, and I don't thing it's the meaning you intend. You probably meant "set" instead. Second, the set $S+T$ is the set of all possible results of adding a member of $S$ with a member of $T$.

Comment: $S+T$ usually means $\{s+t:s\in S,t\in T \}$ in the context of real numbers. In more general spaces, it can sometimes mean the set *generated* by such sums (probably not the case here). So $\sup (S+T)=\sup\{s+t:s\in S,t\in T \}$.

Comment: Okay I understand now. Thanks

Comment: And one more pedantic note, this equation is only valid when the suprema of $T$ and $S$ separately exist. Make an attempt.

Comment: @Ishfaaq You can only run into a problem if one of the sets is empty. Otherwise the possibility of $+\infty$ is not a problem, you just get $+\infty$ on both sides. Assuming the usual convention that $\sup \emptyset = -\infty$, either set being empty can be a problem, because you can get $\infty - \infty$ on the left side, or you can get $-\infty$ on the left side and a finite number on the right side. If you adopt the (nonstandard) convention that $\sup \emptyset = 0$ then there is no problem regardless.

Answer (score 2):

For example, take $S=\{1,\frac12,\frac13,\frac14,\dots\} = \{ \tfrac1m\colon m\ge1\}$ and $T=\{0,\frac12,\frac23\frac34,\dots\} = \{ 1-\tfrac1n\colon n\ge1\}$. So $\sup S=\sup T=1$ in this case, and
$$
S+T = \{s+t\colon s\in S,\,t\in T\} = \{ \tfrac1m + (1-\tfrac1n)\colon m,n\ge1\} = \{ 1+\tfrac1m -\tfrac1n \colon m,n\ge1\}.
$$
You can check that $\sup(S+T)=2$ in this case (as your equation says it should): every element of $S+T$ is less than $2$, while the subset $\{1\}+T=\{ 2-\tfrac1n\colon n\ge1\}$ contains elements arbitrarily close to $2$.